# Excel formula to replace boolean value with specific text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am currently working on an excel sheet which among other things compares risk assessment based on various conditions.

In cell G3 I have the initial risk assessment, in cell L3 I have the new risk assessment. these values will only be "Standard" "Medium" or "High" I am trying to show in cell M3 whether the risk assessment has changed based on the two text fields.

So far I have a simple EXACT function which is =EXACT(G3,L3)

This formula works the way i would like but will only return True or False Boolean values.

how can I adapt this so that it returns a text string of "Yes" or "No"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using an IF function.

IF will execute a formula. If the result is true, the first parameter is executed/returned, if the result is false, the second parameter is executed/returned.

Your formula would become:

```
=IF( EXACT(G3,L3) ; "Yes" ; "No" )
```

Alternatively, something like this could also work:

```
=IF (G3=L3 ; "Yes" ; "No" )
```

The difference is that in the second example, if G3 or L3 refers to a function that generates the same as its counterpart, it will still result in a Yes.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to get the IF function to do this exact thing but could not get my head around it.

Comment: You're welcome. :)